# Transpose the dataset

Tags: sas

I have the original dataset

[image: 1]

What I want is:

[image: 2]

My code:

```
proc transpose data = lib.original 
       out= lib.new(rename=(col1=Mean col2=Median));
       var  WBCmean RBCmean WBCmedian  RBCmedian;
       run;
```

But I get

[image: 3]

Can you give some hint?

**EDIT**

If I add `by` statement,

```
proc transpose data = lib.original 
       out= lib.new;
       by Gender;
       var  WBCmean RBCmean WBCmedian  RBCmedian;
       run;
```

then I get
[image: 4]

Comment: You left out the BY statement to treat Male and Female records as separate groups.  Try that and see if you can get closer.  Also look into using two TRANSPOSE steps.

Comment: @Tom, I added the `by` statement.

Comment: Do you have only those 4 columns or do you need a solution that's dynamic? In general transpose is good cause it's dynamic but if you need a customized result a 'manual' transpose via an array is also good.

Comment: @Reeza, I only have those 4 columns.

Comment: Please include your data as text, not an image, in the future. For testing this means someone has to type in your data manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert to a tall skinny format.

```
proc transpose data = have out=middle ;
  by gender ;
  var WBCmean RBCmean WBCmedian  RBCmedian;
run;
```

Then generate the new variables needed,

```
data middle;
  set middle ;
  testcode = substr(_name_,1,3);
  _name_ = substr(_name_,4);
run;
```

you might need to sort the data depending on the order of variable names in your original VAR statement,

```
proc sort data=middle;
  by gender testcode _name_;
run;
```

and then transpose into the new arrangement.

```
proc transpose data=middle out=want ;
  by gender testcode ;
  id _name_;
  var col1 ;
run;
```

Comment: It is still incorrect. I put the original dataset on [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=3A8BB9EAEEFF1DB%214159&cid=03A8BB9EAEEFF1DB). Hopefully somebody can take a look at it.

Comment: I tested this and it works as expected. Explain what's incorrect.